# jquery onmouseover change div works same with on click won't work

Tags: jquery

i have a modal, inside this modal i load dynamic generate content.

Inside this content is a div and a .

Now i do onmouseover the icon, show the div, and take the data-attribute for select the div and set the new text for div - that all works.

If i try to do the same with on click, it failed, and i dont know why?

Failed mean, that the click fired, call the alert but dont update the dive (dont show them) - even though the alert box tell me the correct id from the data-attribute "data-tooltipdest"...i dont understand that

Thats the html

```
<div id="tooltip_name" class="tooltipboard">This text is show</div>
<i class="far fa-question-circle tooltipflag" data-tooltipdest="tooltip_name" data-tooltiptxt="this text on div"></i>
```

Thats the script (put in the base file, not in the dynamic later loded part)

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".tooltipflag", function() {
        alert("Click dest:"+$(this).attr("data-tooltipdest"));
        $("#"+$(this).attr("data-tooltipdest")).html("<span class=\"tooltip-close\" data-tooltipdest=\""+$(this).attr("data-tooltipdest")+"\">×</span>"+$(this).attr("data-tooltiptxt"));
        $("#"+$(this).attr("data-tooltipdest")).show();
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".tooltipflag, .tooltip-close", function(){
        $("#"+$(this).attr("data-tooltipdest")).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ups, the problem was that the "click" element fired on both function at the same time caused by the same class ".tooltipflag", so i show and hide the div at the same time, what looks like i wont work, but it do exactly that what i have told :-))

So i have remove the ".tooltipflag" from the second function and all works fine :-))

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over your icon, only the first of the two functions will be executed, resulting in the text being updated. Clicking the icon is impossible now, since the alert will be triggered. Changing `mouseover` to `click` will allow both functions to execute, so your text will be updated and hidden afterwards.

Here is an example without hiding the div: https://jsfiddle.net/y4jfkzte/

Comment: yes first function show, second hide the div. And thats my problem "$(document).on("click", ".tooltipflag"," wont work, only "$(document).on("mouseover", ".tooltipflag"," work - and i dont know why

Comment: wont works mean, that the click is fired, the alert is shown, but the div isnt show, whats go in another way, if i click or if i onmouseover?

Comment: Since both function trigger on a single click, the alert is shown and the div hidden directly afterwards. Using a mouseover on the first function triggers on hovering, the function to hide the div is activated on a click. So what do you want the application to do? Clicking on the icon once to trigger the alert? And after this?